# WPF Window_SizeChanged does not always allow Height to change in my scenario

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that hosts a grid. This grid hosts a button on the left, a Custom Control based upon a Wrap Panel in the middle, then another button on the right.

The concept is to have a MaxHeight that moves like the Wrap Panel. When the Width is shrunk so all of the objects do not fit, the Max Height recalculates to allow another row of objects.

The issue I am seeing comes when the panel is wide enough to allow only one row high of objects. When I shrink the width to the point the height should grow, it does not grow unless I release the window grip and then resize the window again.

So, when the Window_SizeChanged() is fired the form will never resize more than the initial MaxHeight even though the MaxHeight is changing during the resize event. The form will shrink and grow height up to the MaxHeight of the form when the mouse button first is pressed.

To get the new window to grow to the larger capable MaxHeight I have to release the mouse button and press it again. It feels like the MaxHeight is not really being increased even though I can verify it is changing to a larger number than the form is allowing me to size to.

Is there a flag I need to set to indicate the MaxHeight has changed?
Is there a better method to dynamically restrict the MaxHeight of the form so it resizes as the design specifies?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Background="#FFC3DC7F" BorderBrush="#FFC3DC7F">X</Button>
    <WrapPanel x:Name="MyPanel" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Width="50" Height="50">A</Button>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50">B</Button>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50">C</Button>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50">D</Button>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50">E</Button>
    </WrapPanel>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Background="#FFC3DC7F" BorderBrush="#FFC3DC7F">O</Button>
</Grid>


private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Int32 itemCount = 5;
  Int32 itemWidth = 50;
  Int32 itemHeight = 50;
  Double panelWidth = MyPanel.ActualWidth;
  Int32 ratio = (Int32)(panelWidth / itemWidth);
  Int32 multiplier = (itemCount - ratio)+1;
  if (multiplier < 1)
    multiplier = 1;
  MaxHeight = (itemHeight * multiplier) + PADDING;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank for you for posting. You have done a good job describing your problem, what you have tried to do, and what you want to do. I'm not sure you need code, but I don't think it would hurt. You might check out the [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help page. I suspect you could shorten your post if you included your code rather than a description of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I could find nothing from MSDN or any forums to help resolve this issue, I found a cheap hack work-around.
I ended up overriding OnRender() and OnRenderSizeChanged() events and removed the built-in MaxHeight setting.
I created my own Double MyMaxHeight, and using OnRender and OnRenderSizeChanged I compare the new Height with my calculated MyMaxHeight. If the Height gets over my setting, I adjust the Height back to my MyMaxHeight.
The negative side effect is there can be flickering of the window size of the larger size window before it is resized down.

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    if (Height > MyMaxHeight)
        Height = MyMaxHeight;
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);
}

protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    if (Height > MyMaxHeight)
        Height = MyMaxHeight;
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
}
```

I kept the Window_SizeChanged() event to calculate my MyMaxHeight flag.

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CalculateFormSize(e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height);
}
```